# Rake db:migrate added default: nil to all tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Today I added a new migration to my rails app and ran rake db:migrate. The migration added a new table.

This resulted in a default of nil being added to all my primary keys. I haven't added any new gems and I deployed some code to staging yesterday.

I am including the change for one table, but this applies to my whole schema.

My rails version is 5.1.4.

Before:

```
  create_table "faqs", id: :integer, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "description", null: false
    t.boolean "default", default: false, null: false
    t.integer "order", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

After:

```
  create_table "faqs", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "description", null: false
    t.boolean "default", default: false, null: false
    t.integer "order", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Here is the migration:

```html
class AddDataProtectionRequest < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :data_protection_requests do |t|
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :first_name, null: false
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.text :body
      t.boolean :data_request, default: false
      t.boolean :data_removal, default: false
      t.string :request_token
      t.datetime :token_expiry

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what was the migration you ran?  Are you using source control and are there any other differences in your code?  If you rollback, does it undo this change?

Comment: Can you export the SQL for the FAQ table? Normally the schema is dumped from the database so if it gets out of sync with the migrations some how (typically a new rails version, or different database version) strange things can happen.

Comment: Did you change/update the database version, on your local machine? That's the most likely cause.

Comment: Why are you declaring id: integer in your migration, and why are you declaring default: nil for it?  Rails handles creating the ID column automatically unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: The schema was likely upgraded when you ran rake db:migrate on your local machine. If the version is different from the production version, then it can cause some issues.

Comment: @BillDoughty that is not the migration. That is from `schema.rb` and the question is why did it add `default: nil` after `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I understand now.  Sorry.  Curious to see the actual migration code.  Now I'm thinking @csexton is probably on the right track.  I'd also be curious to see the output of **mysql> desc faqs;**.

Comment: I am going to update the question with the migration.

Comment: Does it do any harm? It appears you are using MySQL and auto_increment keys. Autoincrement will use the next value available when INSERT is performed with NULL value.